# Azure. Automation of tempDB with ARM templates

Tags: sql-server, azure, dsc, tempdb

I need to automate setting tempDB files on SQL Server 2016 Web Edition with Windows Server 2016 on Azure. Is it possible to do with ARM templates?

Comment: are you talking about IaaS? yes

Comment: Yeah, I need to do it on IaaS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a template ready, but there are examples on quickstart templates with the VM with DSC extensions (https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/dsc-extension-azure-automation-pullserver or https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/sql-reporting-services-sql-server/azuredeploy.json#L331-L365), that's the only real way to do that. You would have to create your own DSC resource based on xDatabase resource, or you can copy someone else's work: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/xSQLServer-PowerShell-12d76584